# Core Data Subquery with !=

Tags: ios, core-data

I have the following subquery which works just fine, however I want to modify it for a != case and it fails as if the subquery is not being executed at all.

```
self.matchType = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(personsCompared, $p, $p.matchType == %@).@count > 0",self.matchTypeField.text];
```

When changed to a not equal query it fails

```
self.matchType = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(personsCompared, $p, $p.matchType != %@).@count > 0",self.matchTypeField.text];
```

It should be pretty straight forward. I have also tried <> for the not equal condition with the same results. Any ideas on this?

Comment: What if `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY personsCompared.matchType != %@", yourText];`? Is there any reason you use a **SUBQUERY**?

Comment: How does it fail? Runtime error/exception? Wrong results?

Comment: Im also confused why you are doing a subquery like this.  But most importantly, what is the failure?